# Query structure in laravel 5 for getting nested array result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I’m trying to make a dynamic resume.
To show the skills I’ve created 3 tables as follows-

1. Skills - Contains all skill with expertise level
2. Groups - Contains category like front end, back end, database, programming etc
3. Skill_Groups - As one skill can be in multiple groups, I made this table. For example- PHP can be back end group also in programming group.

Skills

[image]

Groups

[image]

Skill_Groups

[image]

Now, I would like to display the groups and skills with nested list. Example-

- Front end

  ⁃   HTML

  ⁃   CSS
- Back End

  ⁃   PHP

  ⁃   MySQL

For this, I need a multidimensional array. What should be the query in laravel to get the result on this way?

[This question may be duplicate one, but I didn’t found. If so, please let me know, I will merge/delete it.]

Any alternate solutions also appreciable, if have.

Comment: this is many to many relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Model `Group` you can add relationship

```
public function skills()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'skill_groups');
}
```

In Controller

```
$groups = Group::with('skills')->get();
```

In View

```
@foreach($groups as $group)
    {{ $group->name }}

    @foreach($group->skills as $skill)
        {{ $skill->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```